# How to create the Sprite with the coordinate from camera position?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I was looking for a convenient way to create a sprite using the camera position while walking in the Viewer.
I used this to get camera position.

> const pos = NOP_VIEWER.navigation.getPosition(); //save current camera position

Then put (X,Y,Z) to styledefinition => and create Sprite.
But the coordinate from camera position and the coordinate of DataVisualization Extension use to create Sprite not same.

How can I convert them to the same coordinate ?

Comment: When you say the coordinates are not the same, what exactly do you mean by that? Are they always offset by some specific distance? I'm thinking this could be because of the "global offset" of the model you're loading into the viewer. While the camera coordinates are always in the **world** coordinate system, the DataViz sprite coordinates might be in the **model** coordinate system so you'd need to apply the global offset to them accordingly.

Comment: It would also help to include a screenshot indicating the error/issue.